# Array of Int: Increase value of each element by X

Tags: arrays, integer, sql-update, increment

Assume I have the following table

```
a |b
--|--
1 |{1,2,3}
2 |{1,2,3}
3 |{1,2,3}
```

Column B is an array of integers. Using SQL, I'd like to update column B and increase each element of the array by a value of 3.
The desired end result would look like

```
a |b
--|--
1 |{4,5,6}
2 |{4,5,6}
3 |{4,5,6}
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on postGreSQL, you can do something like this :

drop table if exists arrayz;
create table arrayz(a int, b int[]);
insert into arrayz values (1, '{1,2,3}'::int[]), (2, '{1,2,3}'::int[]), (3, '{1,2,3}'::int[]);

select a, array(select bvalue+1 from unnest(arr.b) as bvalue where a = arr.a)
from arrayz arr;